# Filtrado de Fechas y obtencion de Fechas en java

Tags: java

Tengo una lista de objetos y cada uno tiene una fecha tipo `calendar`. Quiero crear un filtro dada dos fechas que me busque todos los objetos entre esas fechas.

Además quisiera crear un método que me calcule dada la fecha de hoy cual es el mes anterior o la semana anterior.

**EDIT**

es una aplicacion android, tengo un spinner donde tengo como opción, {hoy, ayer, semana anterior, mes anterior, anual} seleccionando alguna de estas debería filtrarme la fecha  según los rangos y segundo cambiarme un textView diciendo de que fecha a que fecha se esta filtrando

```
Calendar actual = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
//fecha inicio    
Calendar c1 = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
//fecha Fin
    public void selectedIntervalo(String intervalo){

        switch (intervalo){

            case "Ir a Hoy":
                datefilter(actual, c1);
                break;
            case "Vista hayer":
                c1.add(Calendar.DATE,-1);
                actual.add(Calendar.DATE,-1);
                c1.add(Calendar.HOUR,24);
                actual.add(Calendar.HOUR,-24);
                datefilter(actual, c1);
                break;
            case "Vista Semana Anterior":
                actual.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR,-1);
                c1.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR,-1);
                datefilter(actual, c1);
                break;
            case "Vista Mensual":
                actual.add(Calendar.MONTH,-1);
                c1.add(Calendar.MONTH,-1);
                datefilter(actual,c1);
                break;
            case "Vista Trimestral":

                break;
            case "Vista Anual":

                break;
            case "Personalizar":

                break;
            default:
                fechaActual();
                break;
        }
    }

    public String datefilter(Calendar date, Calendar i){


        SimpleDateFormat formateador = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM");

        return "Del: " +formateador.format(date)+" hasta el "+formateador.format(i);
    }
```

aun me falta para anual trimestral pero las fecha no me salen como quisiera un ejemplo seria si digo para el mes anterior considerando que hoy es 14/01/2015 debería decirme Del: 01/11/2014 hasta el 31/11/2014

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Tienes algún código en el que hayas estado trabajando?

Comment: No vamos a hacer el trabajo por ti. Que no te funcione el código de una función puede ser una pregunta concreta... que no sepas cómo hacer la función **no** es una pregunta concreta

Comment: Hola Brian Bienvenido a SO en español, podrias decirnos como es tu aplicación es decir, si utilizas swing, awt, gwt, spring, struts o es una aplicacion de consola, asi podriasmos ayudarte mas, ya que desconocemos que necesitas

Comment: @eferion Por favor, seamos más amigables con los novatos. Es mejor un comentario al estilo del que ha escrito jasilva.

Answer (score 4):

Para calcular el inicio y fin del mes anterior primero debes restar un mes al objeto calendar, luego utilizando [`getActualMinimum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getActualMinimum(int)) y [`getActualMaximum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getActualMaximum(int)) obtienes el primero y el ultimo día del mes respectivamente.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo online completo: https://ideone.com/ASkBWB

El código es mas o menos así:

```
// obtenemos la fecha
Calendar fecha = Calendar.getInstance();
// restamos un mes
fecha.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
// calculamos el primer dia del mes anterior
Calendar inicioMesAnterior = (Calendar) fecha.clone(); 
inicioMesAnterior.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, inicioMesAnterior.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
// calculamos el ultimo dia del mes anterior
Calendar finMesAnterior = (Calendar) fecha.clone();
finMesAnterior.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, inicioMesAnterior.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

Debes tener en cuenta que en este ejemplo, ya que estoy clonando la fecha, la hora no sera ni 00:00 ni 23:59 respectivamente. Pero en el ejemplo online de arriba agregue un par de funciones que resuelven este problema (reseteando los valores de hora, minuto, segundo y milisegundo)

### Respuesta Original:

Calendar ya tiene métodos para hacer ambas cosas

Agregar/Reducir una hora, un mes, un día, etc:

```
Calendar cal = modelo.getFecha(); // este es tu objecto
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1); // valores positivos para sumar
```

Verificar un fecha en un rango:

```
Calendar inicioRango = ...; // fecha de inicio
Calendar finRango    = ...; // fecha de fin
Calendar valor       = ...; // fecha a comparar
if (inicioRango.compareTo(valor) <= 0 &&
      finRango.compareTo(valor) >= 0) {
   // valor esta entre inicioRango y finRango
}
```

Puedes ver en la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.MILLISECOND) de Calendar las diferentes opciones de la función `add`.

https://ideone.com/quHsYV

Answer (score 1):

Para facilitar las cosas a la hora de filtrar puedes usar **Lambdas**, pero necesitarás que la propiedad por la que quieres filtrar no sea **private**. Por ejemplo:

```
public class User {
    private String name;
    Calendar birthDate;
    private String address;
    private String phone;
    private String email;

    /* Constructores, getters y setters */
}
```

Si te fijas el campo `birthDate` no lo he hecho privado, esto es porque voy a filtrar por dicho campo. Ahora veamos como filtramos por un rango de fechas: entre `01-01-1990` y `31-12-1992`:

```
Calendar after = Calendar.getInstance();
after.setTime(fmt.parse("01-01-1990"));
Calendar before = Calendar.getInstance();
before.setTime(fmt.parse("31-12-1992"));

List<User> filtered = users.stream().filter(u -> 
                                u.birthDate.after(after) && u.birthDate.before(before))
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

//Interseccion de dos conjuntos de fechas

try 
{

```
        boolean interseccionBoolean = false;
```

SimpleDateFormat formatea = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

```
        Date fechaDesde = formatea.parse("05/05/2017");
        Date fechaHasta = formatea.parse("10/05/2017");            

        //Fechas de corte 

        Date CI = formatea.parse("10/04/2017");
        Date CF = formatea.parse("20/04/2017");

        // Para los casos que se necesite extremos infinitos
        // Date corteDesde = null;
        // Date corteHasta = null;

        corteHasta = (corteHasta == null) ? fechaHasta : corteHasta;
        corteDesde = (corteDesde == null) ? fechaDesde : corteDesde;

        if (!interseccionBoolean && fechaDesde.compareTo(corteDesde) < 0 && fechaHasta.compareTo(corteHasta) > 0) {
            //System.out.print("Caso 1 -> ");
            fechaDesde = corteDesde;
            fechaHasta = corteHasta;
            interseccionBoolean = true;
        }
        if (!interseccionBoolean && fechaDesde.compareTo(corteDesde) > -1 && fechaHasta.compareTo(corteHasta) < 1) {
            //System.out.print("Caso 2 -> ");
            interseccionBoolean = true;
        }

        if (!interseccionBoolean && fechaDesde.compareTo(corteDesde) < 1 && fechaHasta.compareTo(corteHasta) < 1 && fechaHasta.compareTo(corteDesde) > -1) {
            //System.out.print("Caso 3 -> ");
            fechaDesde = corteDesde;
            interseccionBoolean = true;
        }

        if (!interseccionBoolean && fechaDesde.compareTo(corteDesde) > -1 && fechaHasta.compareTo(corteHasta) > -1 && fechaDesde.compareTo(corteHasta) < 1) {
            //System.out.print("Caso 4 -> ");
            fechaHasta = corteHasta;
            interseccionBoolean = true;
        }

        if (interseccionBoolean) {
            System.out.print("Fecha INI " + fechaDesde.toString() + "  ** -- ** Fecha FIN " + fechaHasta.toString());
        } else {
            System.out.print("Interseccion CERO no hay nada que evaluar");
        }

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        //System.out.print("error");
    }
```

Comment: Por favor explica un poco como tu código responde a la pregunta y soluciona el problema planteado.

Answer (score 0):

esta es la manera correcta:

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
Calendar c1 = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
c1.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");
dateFormat.setTimeZone(cal.getTimeZone());
String strDate = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
System.out.println(strDate);
```

Comment: Hola, favor de indicar por qué consideras que es la manera correcta o el razonamiento que te llevó a hacerlo así. Si compartes únicamente el código tu respuesta podría no ser útil a personas con poblemas similares o relacionados que consulten esta pregunta en un futuro.

Comment: Esta respuesta ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad y debería ser mejorada. Como bien te dice Ruslan, sería ideal que añadieras una descripción de por qué ésta sería la manera correcta y cómo funciona. Te recomiendo que leas [answer] en el centro de ayuda, donde encontrarás consejos útiles para mejorar esta respuesta.